# Outlook 2007 /2003 Keeps asking for Password repeatedly

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, exchange, outlook-2007, outlook-2003

Every time you open outlook 2003/ 2007 outlook keeps asking for the password repeatedly, even though you entered correctly/ you have saved it, its keeps prompting for the password!!! Please can someone Help me to find a solution for this problem?

Comment: Is the offending computer joined to the same domain as your Exchange server?

Comment: Are you using gmail? I've seen this when google has server issues.

Comment: as i know it is not on the same domain..because the server is in head office.

Answer (score 1):

Is this happening for all users or just one user? If just one, make sure the account is not locked or disabled.

Comment: no it happened to all users in our network but..later on some uses outlook got ok..but still 2-3 users still facing this problems

Comment: How distributed is your domain?  Is it all one site?  Are the affected users at a different site than your Exchange server(s)?  Sounds like you might have a sync / replication problem.

Comment: there are two servers one is at head office other one is at our office some uses are using head office server...some are using our office site server...i tryed with both but ddnt work...

Answer (score 0):

I kept getting this once.  My Mail server was running on Ubuntu, and once I stopped and Re-Started the mail server all was ok.

Answer (score 0):

Do the prompts stop eventually? Try adding the credentials of the users to the Credential Manager (WinXP: Start>Run>control keymgr.dll>OK).

Also add the name of the server and any other mail server identities (mail.domain.com; autodiscover.domain.com; domain.com; etc) to the exceptions list in Internet Connections. It's under LAN Settings on the Connections Tab - you have to tick Use Proxy Server to enter in exceptions. You can untick when you're done.

Doing the above has helped get rid of prompting before. You can even add your mail server's detail to the Hosts file for good measure.

Comment: can u explain your answer a little deeply i didn't understand please.

Comment: Okay I saw that you're using different domains. I dealt with this situation not too long ago.

1. On the users computer, save the users Exchange/Head Office account details to the Credential Manager (search for it in Windows 7). In Windows XP you save credentials by running the following: Start>Run> control keymgr.dll >OK. Make sure its in the domain\user format, and enter the location of the Exchange server.

Comment: 2. Go into the local computers exceptions list. Find it in Control Panel>Internet Options - Connections Tab - LAN Settings. Enable 'Use a Proxy' and click Advanced. Add your domain, your Exchange address, the Exchange server IP, and other mail server items like exchangesrvr.domain.xx; autodiscover.domain.xx; domain.xx etc.

Click OK and untick 'Use a Proxy'. Click OK all the way out.

Comment: 3. Add your server to the Hosts file. Find your Hosts file in \Windows\System32\drivers\etc and open with Notepad. Below the # add in your Exchange servers' IP and its Name (see the localhost example in the file). You shouldn't need to add in any other items.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue on our office PCs. It turned out to be an issue with IIS and pre-Service Pack 2 PCs.

http://www.techieshelp.com/outlook-prompts-for-credentials/